# Sending video frame from backend to frontend 120 fps

Tags: javascript, opencv, base64, video-streaming, video-processing

I am sending video from frontend to backend using html form.After object detection I have to send objection detection video frames from backend to frontend now I am  converting each frame to base64 and sending to frontend using api but it is very slow is there other better way to do that

Comment: Why is this up-voted? It has no useful or technical information about the situation. Ok the problem is slowness, but what is slow... Is it large frame size? Is it slow internet speed? Need a faster detection algorithm? Is it Base64 that is slow? Not obvious where your problem lies in this whole process...

Comment: PS: What information is returned in the _"objection detection video frames from backend to frontend"_? Is it a rectangle marking the area or is it a text label? I mean can't you just receive the rectangle's coordinates, or maybe receive the text of label? Does it work faster if you resize the pixels to a smaller size? Does it work faster if you don't Base64 anything?

Comment: Opencv return frame in nd array format to send this frame to frontend I am converting it to base64 but this conversion takes 40 ms for 1 frame if I reduce size of image to 400×500px.

Comment: newbies always use base64 because they don't understand that HTTP is perfectly capable of moving binary data. the solution is to **stop using base64**.